# Build for shared library without a .so file

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ld

I'm compiling C source which calls a shared library, and have only the library header on the build machine, not the .so file (different cpu architecture). How do I make the code find and load /usr/lib/libx.so at runtime?

Comment: Add your lib directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: If you use `dlopen` it will search `/lib` and `/usr/lib` (in that order) automatically.

Comment: Would I call dlsym as well, or use the original symbol names and build with -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files?

Answer (score 3):

Create a 'dummy' libx.so file that exports the needed symbols.

Answer (score 2):

*REVISED from original suggestion of LD_LIBRARY_PATH.*

Assuming you are on a linux system, shared libraries may be loaded before execution starts via the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libx.so" your_app
```

However, linking with `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files` is probably not a good practice.  I'd recommend using `dlsym` to load arbitrary symbols from a dynamic library.  For example,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main ()
{
   void *handle;
   void (*foo_fp) (void);  // function signature from dynamic library

   // Dynamically load libfoo.so, searching it from LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   handle = dlopen ("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY);

   // Load function 'foo' from libfoo.so
   foo_fp = dlsym(handle, "foo");

   // Calls 'foo' from libfoo.so
   foo_fp();
   return 0;
}
```

To compile this:

```
gcc -o main main.c -ldl
```

To execute:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<location of libfoo.so>
./main
```

Comment: Does not work; probably since it was built without -l*

Comment: Can you clarify how you built the executable?  This reference may help you as well: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Comment: gcc -o app src.c -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files

Comment: Try: `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libx.so; ./app`

Comment: Works! But the semicolon is not necessary. Now if only I could get the same effect at build time...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at build time?

Comment: I'd like to build the app to load libx.so on startup without having to use -lx. If that's not possible, I'll settle for LD_PRELOAD=libx.so

Comment: The dlopen() idea should be a separate answer. I believe dlopen() by itself has the same effect as LD_PRELOAD. I definitely don't want to call dlsym() for each shared lib routine.

Answer (score 1):

Using the library header file we can create a dummy `libx.so` using a valid `x.c` file with blank implementations.

We can use this `libx.so` file to link to our executable while building it. Once the executable is built we can replace the dummy `libx.so` file with the real `libx.so` file and it will work properly.

I have tested this approach with `gcc` and found it to work. I wonder if there is a straightforward way to do this.

This might be helpful to follow the steps https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html.